# can a enum variable garbage collected?

Tags: c#, enums, garbage-collection

Normally all reference types are garbage collected when it is having no reference. What about a enum variable? will it be garbage collected even if it is out of scope(means it is not referenced more)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Garbage collection for ValueType wrappers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415995/garbage-collection-for-valuetype-wrappers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do value types get Garbage collected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342772/do-value-types-get-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum is a value type variable so it is automatically <strike>released</strike> forgotten when it falls out of scope.

Comment: Unless it's been boxed, or it's actually a member of a reference type, or the jitter decides to allocate it on the heap which it's perfectly entitled to do if it feels like it.....  But in the general case - yes - probably.

Comment: It is not a very accurate answer.  There is no 'released' it is just forgotten.  And it has nothing to do with scope.  Well, barely.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very confusingly written.

> Normally all reference types are garbage collected when it is having no reference.

Reference *types* are not collected. *Instances* of reference types are collected.  And they are not collected when the instance has no references. They are collected *when the garbage collector runs and determines that the referenced object cannot be reached from a known-to-be-alive root*.

> What about a enum variable? will it be garbage collected even if it is out of scope (means it is not referenced more)?

The *scope* of a variable is the region of program text in which the variable may be accessed by its name. The *scope* of a variable is only loosely connected to its *lifetime*, which is what you are asking about. The lifetime of a variable may be longer or shorter than the period of time that program control is in its scope!

Also, it is completely unclear what you mean by "will an enum variable be garbage collected?" Variables are storage locations, so the variable has to *be* somewhere. **Where is the variable**?  Is it a field of a class? is it a local variable? Is it a closed-over outer variable of a lambda? Is it an element of an array of enumerated type? All of these affect whether the storage associated with the variable is collected, and if it is, when it is collected.

Your question doesn't really make any sense the way you've asked it. Can you clarify the question?

You might also want to read my answer to this related question:

[Do value types get Garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342772/do-value-types-get-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration in C# is a value type so will follow the rules of garbage collection for value types, which defers based on declaration scope of that type. You can find a lot information on internet. Here is an example link of reference and value types comparison also from GC perspective.

http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx